# ¿Cómo pasar el valor de una variable PHP a una funcion Angular?

Tags: php, angularjs

necesito de vuestra ayuda, ¿alguien podria instruirme en como puedo yo pasar el valor de una variable declarada en un archivo PHP a una funcion en Angular para mostrarla como mensaje cuando ocurra o no un cierto evento, como cuando tratamos de eliminar un cierto objeto de nuestra BD?

Ejemplo (Funcion angular):

```
$scope.deleteDependenciaPunto = function(id_punto)   
{
            if(confirm("¿Estás seguro(a) de eliminar esta dependencia?"))
            {
                $http.post("mainApp/Delete/deleteDependenciaPunto.php",
                {
                  'id_punto':$scope.id_punto,
                  'id_puntoDependencia':$scope.id_puntoDependencia
                })
               .then(function(datosDeleteDependencia)
               {
                 $scope.contentDependencia = datosDeleteDependencia;             
               },function errorCallback(datosDeleteDependencia)
               {
                 alert("¡Ups! ha ocurrido un error, por favor comunicate con nosotros.")
               });
            }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }

}
```

PHP (Condicion):

```
if(mysqli_query($mysqli, $deleteDependencia))
    {
      echo 'Datos eliminados correctamente';
      //Declarar variable...
    }
    else
    {
       echo "Error al eliminar los datos: " . $mysqli->error;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como estas haciendo peticiones a tu archivo php, basta con el que la funcion php retorne datos.

Ejemplo :

```
$resultado = array(
    'mensaje' => '',
    'variable' => 0
);
if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $deleteDependencia)) {
    $resultado['mensaje'] = "Datos eliminados correctamente";
    $resultado['variable'] = "Valor de tu variable";
} else {
    $resultado['mensaje'] = "Error al eliminar los datos: ";
    $resultado['variable'] = 0;
}
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

Y en tu funcion angular

```
$http.post("mainApp/Delete/deleteDependenciaPunto.php", {
    'id_punto': $scope.id_punto,
    'id_puntoDependencia': $scope.id_puntoDependencia
})
.then(function(datosDeleteDependencia) {
    $scope.mensajeDependencia = datosDeleteDependencia.mensaje;
    $scope.variable = datosDeleteDependencia.variable;
}, function errorCallback(datosDeleteDependencia) {
    alert(datosDeleteDependencia.mensaje);
});
```

Comment: Probé, pero 

$scope.mensajeDependencia = datosDeleteDependencia.mensaje;
$scope.variable = datosDeleteDependencia.variable;

traen undefined.

Comment: puedes imprimir lo que te trae datosDeleteDependencia?

Comment: Si, este es el resultado, "Datos eliminados correctamente<br>Valor de tu variable{"mensaje":"Datos eliminados correctamente","variable":"Valor de tu variable"}"

Comment: borra eso de "Datos eliminados correctamente<br>Valor de tu variable", el mensaje lo agrege a tu respuesta ya no es necesario el `echo`, copia mi codigo completo

Comment: data:Object
   mensaje:"Datos eliminados correctamente"
     variable:"Valor de tu variable"

Esto es lo que trae el objeto, pero aun asi cuando imprimo las variables estan indefinidas

Comment: Listo, amigo mio, me sirvio tu ayuda, 

$scope.msjStateDependencia = datosDeleteDependencia.data.mensaje;
$scope.variable = datosDeleteDependencia.data.variable;
Lo solucioné de esta manera, me salvaste!

Comment: excelente! @jecorrales si te sirvio mi respuesta recuerda marcarla :D

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una función en php que retorne tu mensaje
Cuando estes en tu vista haz una consulta a tu función con el servicio http despues de cargar la pagina,

algo así

PHP

```
 public function mensaje()
{
  return "Error en mensaje";
}
```

HTML, cuando defines tu controlador define la consulta

```
<div ng-controller="tuController as dato" ng-init='nombre_Funcion()'>
</div>
```

Y por ultimo la consulta con angular

AngularJS, haces la consulta y luego atraes la respuesta y la colocas en una variable global

```
$scope.nombre_Funcion= function()
{
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: 'url de la funcion'
    })

    .then(function (response)
    {
        $scope.mensaje_error = response.data;

    });
};
```